# Trouble recovering data from corrupted PostgreSQL tables

Tags: postgresql, restore, corruption

I'm trying to recover my database after a recent corruption of the same. Now I have two tables that are really giving me trouble.

When I do `select count(*)` One table returns:

> ERROR:  could not access status of transaction 2619431010
>   DETAIL: Could not open file "pg_clog/09C2": No such file or directory.

The other one returns:

> ERROR:  invalid page header in block 94206 of relation
>   base/11974232/11975439

Is there a way I can work around and get my data back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About this error:

> ERROR: invalid page header in block 94206 of relation
>   base/11974232/11975439

You could issue `SET zero_damaged_pages TO ON` and retry.
It will not rewrite any page to disk, just in memory. Assuming it works, the idea is to run `COPY bad TO 'file'` to dump as much valuable data as possible.

(that's also assuming that `11975439` is the OID of a table, not an index. If it's an index, you may just drop it).

Comment: How do I identify whether `11975439` is OID or INDEX?

Comment: `select relname from pg_class where oid=11975439`. (it's no OID or index, it's the OID of a table or the OID of an index).

Comment: The above query returns `ac_ledger` does this mean `11975439` is an OID of the table `ac_ledger` ?

Comment: Yes. And if this error happens when you were doing `select count(*) from ac_ledger` that would totally make sense.

Comment: Your solution worked, because I can get results when I run a `select`, but I dont know why the connection to the db is terminating when I don't `limit`. Am dealing with a large database.

Comment: That could be a backend crash, you need to look at the server logs for confirmation. See http://blog.endpoint.com/2010/06/tracking-down-database-corruption-with.html for a similar case.

Answer (score 5):

[The very first thing you should do when you encounter database corruption](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption) is to capture a filesystem copy of the data directory tree while PostgreSQL is not running and save it somewhere safe.

Once you have done that, if you do not have a backup which you can restore you might want to try [pg_resetxlog](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgresetxlog.html).  Note that the documentation has this recommendation:

> You should immediately dump your data, run initdb, and reload. After
>   reload, check for inconsistencies and repair as needed.

Read over the [documentation page for `pg_resetxlog`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgresetxlog.html) until you understand the options and which might be best for your situation.

Finally, make sure you understand how the database was corrupted.

- Usually this is due to bad hardware or drivers.
- Sometimes it is due to usage of non-default PostgreSQL settings which allow DBAs to reduce reliability to improve performance.  Some shops with redundant servers find this a worthwhile trade-off, because losing one server in a large redundant server farm is no big deal.  You may hear this sort of configuration referred to as "DBAs running with scissors" and consists primarily of turning off `fsync`, `full_page_writes`, and `synchronous_commit` -- all of which are needed to ensure persistence of committed transactions.  The first two are required to prevent database corruption on a crash of the OS or hardware.  You should not turn these off unless it is OK to lose the entire PostgreSQL instance.
- Rarely, people delete some integral part of their database, such as the `pg_xlog` or `pg_clog` subdirectory.
- Even more rarely, there is a PostgreSQL bug which caused the corruption.  Because any report of such a bug is treated very seriously, they tend to get fixed very quickly and are generally encountered these days by people running outdated versions which are out of support.  Without knowing the exact version (the output from `SELECT version();`), it's hard to know whether you are vulnerable to a known, fixed bug.  Possibly relevant to this particular error message is whether you used pg_upgrade and exactly which version of that you used.

Comment: My case is as a result of hardware issue after some power surge. Am now trying to recover as much data as I can since there was no reliable backup. I however have a copy of data directory which Am using for the repair attempts.

Comment: Yeah, that tends to make pg_resetxlog sound like the next step after ensuring you have a good filesystem level copy of where you are right now.

Comment: I have tried pg_resetxlog and am getting this output `Transaction log reset` but when I run the `select count(*)` , I still get the same error output as above @kgrittn ?

Comment: It looks like you will need to do some manual work on the pg_clog files. What OS is this? What do you get when you run `pg_resetxlog -n` (with your data directory)?

Comment: this is the result from pg_resetxlog -n ` Am running fedora 16 32 bit am getting some results which apparently I cant share in this comment - Its more than the required characters for a comment, but I here's an excerpt `First log file ID after reset:        0
First log file segment after reset:   1
pg_control version number:            843
Catalog version number:               200904091
Database system identifier:           5757969149907954287
Latest checkpoint's TimeLineID:       1
Latest checkpoint's NextXID:          0/656
Latest checkpoint's NextOID:          11565

` `